# Getting static image of Google Map

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

I am doing golf game oriented project. In that I have to integrate "img" format of map. How do I integrate this map into my project...or any other format of map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static Maps may fit your use case: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

But **check the Terms of Use** — both the usage limits (at that URL) and the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) 10.1.1(h).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Static Maps API from Google. You can produce a query string and it'll point to a GIF you can download.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example